# how to Display AlertDialog in android after specified time (3 min)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i want to display AlertDialog in my activity for a message to a user that shows "Try Again !" . with one button of 'OK' .On click of button OK , go to Mainactivity
But AlertDialog Display after finish ProgressBar (3min)

Comment: You should search for two things separately, i.e. how to delay & how to display alert.

Comment: I know that how to display alert but I'm looking for how to delay :)

Comment: There are a number of ways, I would suggest looking into something like a `Handler` with it's `postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long duration)` method to post the alertDialog, where the duration is `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Show your dialog here
        }
}, 1000 * 60 * 3);
```

Here postDelayed method gets 2nd parameter as an int (future time in milliseconds). After that specified time "run" method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
new Thread(new Runnable(

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            int progress = 0;
            while (progress < 100) {
                // update progressbar with handler and setProgress(progress);
                Thread.sleep(3000/times);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }
        //Show dialog :)
    }
}).start();
```

If you want a progress bar being showed, you can use a while(times) and set the sleep to 3000/times and each time it wakes up you update the progressbar in the main thread with a handler.

Comment: AlertDialog will appear after the end of the ProgressBar ?